# Bind gridview with webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am developing Android application and trying to retrieve data from one server to display data into the android grid through a web service. I created a web service in .net and connected to server in that web service application. Now the problem is, I have data in xml file and I don't know how to bind that XML data in android GridView, if anyonw knows, please post the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. watch this:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

(yeah, i know its aprox. 1h, no code, etc ... but it's worth to watch, really)

1. use JSON instead of xml
2. cache data in local sqlite db
3. use data from cache